# Telling WebView to cache all pages no matter the HTML meta-tag no-cache

Tags: android, android-webview

Is there a way to direct the webview to cache pages even if the page has meta-tags requesting the page not be cached? I don't want to reload cnn, or wikipedia page each time again if I have already visited the page but these sites contain meta tags generated on the server requesting cache not be used.